# Deserializing via JSON.NET with Variable Property Name

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Given some json that looks like

```
{
  "id":"123_678",
  "fs_123_678":
   {
     "title":"Apple Parts",
     "data": 134
   }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize it into the following classes

```
public class Result
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public ResultInfo Info {get; set;}
}

public class ResultInfo
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public int Data {get; set;}
}
```

... but that second property (`fs_123_678`) is not a fixed name.  I've looked at other similar posts on SO here, and the common solution is to use a `IDictionary<string, MyPoco>` however, that only works when the variable data is *not* at the root level.  **The name of the property is 100% predictable**, and I could describe in code what it will be for a given JSON response based off of values used in the source HTTP request.  The trick is, how do I let the JSON deseralizer in on the business rule around what it will be called for this given deserialization?  I basically need something that would act like `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = *insert logic here*)]` (which of course isn't possible).

What's a reasonable way to approach this, all while retaining the "for free" strong-typed deserialization of the rest of the object?

Comment: I'd write a custom deserializer (JSON.NET has a great article about it on their site).

Comment: @SamAxe awesome, I was looking in the "Serializing and Deserializing JSON" section (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) and I didn't see anything that would help me out - but maybe I missed it?  Got a handy dandy link by chance?

Comment: You could use `[JsonTypedExtensionData]` and `TypedExtensionDataConverter<ResultInfo>` from [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094403/3744182).  Or you could write a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `Result` as shown in, say, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017892/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30179162/3744182).

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Can someone link to the "similar" posts? I've also searched, but I can't find them, and it sounds like I can use dictionaries but its not clear how to me.

Comment: Potentially this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507667/deserialize-json-with-variable-property-names

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links that [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) provided in comments, I found that this solution appears to be functional, but open to other suggestions.  I'm bascially taking the current reader stream, loading it as a `JObject` then replacing the original `JProperty` with another that has the name my model is expecting.

```
public class MyCustomResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var formData = obj.SelectToken("fs_" + obj.SelectToken("id").Value<string>());
        formData.Parent.Replace(new JProperty("info", formData));

        existingValue = existingValue ?? new FormActionResult();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), existingValue);
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Result).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomResultConverter))]
public class Result
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public ResultInfo Info {get; set;}
}
```