# Newtonsoft JSON serialization - how to flatten a reference type field

Tags: json, json.net, flatten, json-serialization, jsonconvert

I have a class (MyClass), in which there is a reference type field (let's call MyNestedClass).
I'm using Newtonsoft, and I would like to serialize this class, including this field. But instead of "opening a new block" in the Json (a Json object), I would like this field to remain in the same level as the other (primitive) fields of this class. It's guaranteed, that the MyNestedClass contains only one field.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nested_prop", Required = Required.Always)]
        public MyNestedClass NestedProp { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

```
    public class MyNestedClass
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

output (with some values):

```
{
    "name" : "foo_val",
    "nested_prop" : {
        "Address" : "bar_val"            // it gets its name (Address) by default (based on the prop name)
    }
}
```

what I want:

```
{
    "name" : "foo_val",
    "address" :  "bar_val"
}
```

(of course I have my reasons why do I need a separate class (MyNestedClass) instead of putting that string (Address) into the MyClass class)

I tried to create a converter (`CustomCreationConverter`) with overriding the `WriteJson` method, but it never gets called during the serialization process...

================================================

Edit:

I used `CustomCreationConverter` because I have already overridden its `Create` method (my prop type in my real problem is an interface, and not the concrete class)

As @dbc hinted, `WriteJson` hasn't been called because in `CustomCreationConverter` the `CanWrite` method is overriden with `return false`. Overriding also this method in my custom converer solves this problem.

Comment: You need to a custom to converter to `MyClass` not `MyNestedClass`.  [Can I serialize nested properties to my class in one operation with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30175911/3744182) is one example.  In fact this may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Incidentally [`CustomCreationConverter<T>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs#L99) is not a useful class for you to inherit from because is designed for customization of **object construction**.  As such it overrides `CanWrite => false;` which is why your `WriteJson()` is never called.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

@dbc indeed that was the problem why ```WriteJson``` was never called. I override the ```CanWrite``` prop getter to return true instead of false, now ```WriteJson``` is called.

(I used ```CustomCreationConverter``` because I already override the ```Create``` method (due to I use interface as reference type and not the concrete class)