# Can I collapse/ignore levels when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using a REST API from C# with Newtonsoft.Json.  The responses include an extra, useless level.

The JSON looks like:

```
{
   'name': 'John Doe',
   'aliases': {
       'member': [
           'Lil Johnny',
           'John Boy'
       ]
   }
}
```

and I want to deserialize into something like:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Aliases { get; set; }
}
```

I'm hoping there's some `JsonProperty` directive I can use to decorate `Aliases` to get the deserializer to discard "member" level of the Json but I can't find it.

Comment: There's no attribute for that, you need to use a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).  For example, [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33088462/3744182) or [Can I serialize nested properties to my class in one operation with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30175911/3744182).

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you, @dbc.